# Some misunderstanding between me and Scheme

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, r5rs

I'm just started learning scheme and can't quite understand why this function does not work:

```
;(define (sort l)
  (define (sorted? l)
    (if (= (length l) 2)            
        ; if simple list:
        (if (< (head l) (tail l)) 
            #t  
            #f) 
        ; if complex list:
        (if (and (< (head l) (head (tail l))) 
                 (sorted? (tail l)))
            #t  
            #f)))
```

Output:

> > (sorted? (1 0)) . . procedure application: expected procedure,
> >     given: 1; arguments were: 0
> >     (sorted? '(1 0)) . . <: expects type  as 2nd argument, given:
> >     (0); other arguments were: 1

Racket, R5RS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you compare an integer and a list, `cadr` or `if (< (head l) (head (tail l)))` instead of `if (< (head l) (tail l))` after a line `; if simple list` would have more chances to work for you.

The following definition works for me:

```
(define (sorted? xs)
  (cond
    ((<= (length xs) 1)
     #t)
    ((< (car xs) (cadr xs))
     (sorted? (cdr xs)))
    (else #f)))
```

Comment: you're right! However, how do I "unlist" a list? like (2) -> 2

Comment: @Halst: As long as `(2)` is equivalent to `(cons 2 (list))`, you can get your value from a singleton with just `car`: `(car (cons 2 (list)))` will return `2`, a head ("cons") of the list.

Answer (score 1):

What scheme do you use?
In R5RS (scheme standard), use car and cdr to get head and tail.

And cdr will give you PAIR, not atom.
That's working.

(define (sorted? l)
    (if (= (length l) 2)
        ; if simple list:
        (if (< (car l) (cadr l)) 
            #t
            #f) 
        ; if complex list:
        (if (and (< (head l) (head (tail l))) 
                 (sorted? (tail l)))
            #t
            #f)))